# Why Clover report doesn't include all my packages?

Tags: junit, clover

I'm new in clover and testing it against my product.

I have setup clover for ant and building my jars and running my juint tests. Thats working fine but when i see the application code coverage report it says 72% but in the package list below , i just see 7 packages listed, whereas i have more than 15 packages.
 Question 1: Is that 72% code coverages are over my all packages or over just listed 7 packages?

Question 2: If its not over all my packages than why clover is not covering/reporting those packages as 0% covered? and how can i include them to report?

Note : i have no junit running against those missing packages , that i klnow. but still i want to list it as 0% to see how much % my existing junits are covering over all my packages.

Thanks
Saiket

Answer (score 0):

Clover reports should list all instrumented packages, even if there's no code coverage for them. Non-covered code is counted in to the total coverage.

You can have to configuration problem regarding missing packages:

- Include/Exclude patterns are miss-configured and omit some files, please refer [file and fileset settings](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup)
- You're having complex Ant project, in which some targets are called from other ones and not all environment properties are passed between them. Please refer to [**inheritrefs="true"**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVERKB/Properties+such+as+Excludes+is+not+being+passed+on+to+antcall+tasks) flag

Cheers